# php eval() returns

Tags: php, eval

```
<?php
  $a = "a == a";
  eval($a);
```

This returns false. I thought it's supposed to return true. Any thoughts/ideas why this is so.

Comment: What is $a = "a == a"; supposed to mean? Everything about that looks incorrect, unless you want $a to equal the string "a == a", in which case carry on.

Comment: maybe you are trying to say `eval("'a' == 'a'")`, this is valid therefore it will be evaluated and will return true

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Straight from the PHP documentation:

> eval() returns NULL unless return is called in the evaluated code, in which case the value passed to return is returned. If there is a parse error in the evaluated code, eval() returns FALSE and execution of the following code continues normally.

Looks like there is a syntax error somewhere in your string.

Comment: `"a == a"` is not valid PHP code (unless `a` is a defined constant).

Answer (score 1):

I think this way of using `eval()` may work in other languages (JavaScript comes to mind), but it doesn't in PHP.

Issuing the command "Evaluate the following expression: `a == a`" makes sense and is right to expect true. But PHP's `eval()` doesn't work that way. It is a simple, primitive method to send code to the interpreter. If you eval()ed

```
eval("$b = 5; $a = $b == $b;");
```

`$a` would be true afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure about your intentions for the code, since there has been no response. If you're wanting to figure out if a variable is equal to a variable by the same name you can find out by doing this:

This returns true:

```
$a = $a == $a;
var_dump($a);
```

This returns false:

```
$b = 5;

$a = $a == $b;
var_dump($a);
```

Just a stab in the dark at why someone would write the block of code in the original post.